# Geocoded node map visualizers?

Tags: data-visualization

I'm looking to create a map like the one below for shipment volume between cities (which I have geocoded). I found the image [below](https://blog.gephi.org/tag/geocoding/) created in Gephi, however I'm wondering what other tools exist that can do similar visualizations. I see it's possible in R though a [code example isn't posted](http://paulbutler.org/archives/visualizing-facebook-friends/).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not so long ago I was using [Gephi](http://gephi.github.io/) to do similar visualizations for graphs. The program is easy to use and it will not take more then a day to learn majority of the [features](http://gephi.github.io/features/). I would say that by the scale `powerfullness / ease of use` it will be the first one.

You can also do this with a lot of JS libraries (few examples):

- [D3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery)
- [sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/)

[Few](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html) examples [with](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/) D3. But it is much harder to produce such graphs there.

---

Just for illustration purposes, I will add here a few images created with Gephi:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice! Though the questions specifically asks for option other than Gephi (the first link was actually from Gephi), so I am not sure if OP will find this answer useful.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight oh, I have not looked at the link. I just read the question and noticed R. Sorry for this. If someone will be too much frustrated with this answer - please write me to remove it. One more time, sorry.

Comment: Do not worry, I just commented so that you realize that. It seems like a neat program and deserves to be shown as an answer.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight thank you. Good things about it is easy learning curve, a lot of functionality out of the box, easy to modify with custom plugins.

Comment: I don't mind Gephi if that is the only option. There seems to be plugins made for geographical data. I just couldn't find any other tools so I was wondering if that was essentially the only one out there.

Comment: @ElPresidente this is not the only one, but I would say the easiest one to use and yet super powerful. I will add some JS libraries as well in a few minutes.